# python output with tooo much characters

Tags: python, printing, binary, output, decimal

i have a little problem in my code.
When I display it I get the number and "0b" at the beginning.
And what I want to do is to get rid of that "0b" and get just number.For example:

> 11000

so here's my code:

```
import time
dec = input("decimal number: ")
decimal = int(dec)
print(decimal,"in binary is:",bin(decimal))
time.sleep(4)
```

and that's my output:

```
decimal number: 24
24 in binary is: 0b11000
```

(giving other numbers doesn't change anything)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just slice it.

```
print(decimal,"in binary is:",str(bin(decimal))[2:])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see its starting to work but how do I discard the "b" too ?              decimal number: 34
34 in binary is: b100010

Comment: Could you try again? Because for number 34, it gives 100010.

Comment: Thank you !! Now it works perfectly (I'm kind of new and I didn't know how to do that)